# change selected tab when navigate to the screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

i am building react native application and i have 2 screens on my app right now.

Home:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import {StackScreens} from '../routes/MyStack'
import {NativeStackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

type homePropsType = NativeStackScreenProps<StackScreens, 'Home'>;

export const Home = (props : homePropsType) => {
    const {navigation} = props;

    const goToProfile =() =>{
    navigation.navigate('Profile'); 
}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        HOME!
      </Text>

      <Button title='profile' color="blue" onPress={goToProfile}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Profile:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,Button } from 'react-native';
import {StackScreens} from '../routes/MyStack'
import {NativeStackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

type profilePropsType = NativeStackScreenProps<StackScreens, 'Profile'>;

export const Profile = (props: profilePropsType) => {

    const {navigation, route} = props;

    const goToHome =() =>{
        navigation.navigate('Home'); 
    }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        profile
      </Text>

      <Button title='home' color="blue" onPress={goToHome}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

MyStack:

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import {Home} from "../screens/Home";
import {Profile} from "../screens/Profile";


export type StackScreens = {
  Home : undefined,
  Profile : undefined
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<StackScreens>();

export const MyStack = (props: any) => (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ title: "", headerShown: false }} >
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

MyTab:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"; 
import {Home} from "../screens/Home";
import {Profile} from "../screens/Profile";
import { MyStack } from "./MyStack";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

export type TabScreens = {
  Home : undefined,
  Profile : undefined,
  MyStack : undefined
}


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabScreens>();

export const MyTab = (props: any) => (
 <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="MyStack" screenOptions={{
    tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:"blue"},
    tabBarActiveTintColor:"white",
   headerShown:false,
 }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="MyStack" component={MyStack} options={{tabBarLabel:"home", tabBarIcon:        ({color}) =>(
        <Icon color={color} name="home" type="font-awesome" />)}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{ tabBarIcon:({color}) =>(
        <Icon color={color} name="user" type="font-awesome" />)}}/>
 </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

Now i can navigate between the to screens with MyStack by press the button on each screen or with MyTab by press on one of the tabs.
My problem is that i want that when i navigate to the profile screen for example the profile tab will be the one that selected. right now if i  perss the button to navigate to the profile screen i will navigate to him but the tab will stay on home.
Is there a way to fix this or that should be like that?

Answer (score 1):

### PROBLEM:

Your navigation structure is :

APP

- Tabs:

  1. MyStack.

     - Home
     - ProfileScreen
  2. ProfileScreen.

The reason of unexpected behaviour is when you are navigating from home to profile screen it is still in **MyStack** and hence the tab bar will show Mystack.

### SOLUTION:

Your `home.js` and `Profile.js` will be same as they are. Just remove myStack as it is not needed.

**MYTAB**

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs"; 
import {Home} from "../screens/Home";
import {Profile} from "../screens/Profile";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";

export type TabScreens = {
  Home : undefined,
  Profile : undefined
}


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabScreens>();

export const MyTab = (props: any) => (
 <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{
    tabBarStyle:{backgroundColor:"blue"},
    tabBarActiveTintColor:"white",
   headerShown:false,
 }}>
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{tabBarLabel:"home", tabBarIcon:        ({color}) =>(
        <Icon color={color} name="home" type="font-awesome" />)}}/>
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{ tabBarIcon:({color}) =>(
        <Icon color={color} name="user" type="font-awesome" />)}}/>
 </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

Now the tab will change when navigating to Profile.
Happy coding.

Comment: but that not solve my problem if i add another screen that not also tab lets name home Screen1. when i move between profile to home the tabs will change but also if i add to the MyStack the screen1 i could not navigate to him

Comment: Then in that case you will not call myStackin MyTab rather you will call MyTab in MyStack. Understood?

Answer (score 0):

There are two screens named "Profile" in `MyStack` and inside `MyTab`.
Try to make sure each screen has a unique name.

Comment: i dont think this is an option because the name should be the screen name no?

Comment: There are 2 screens named "Profile" available to your stack.
The reason you see the profile screen and don't see the selected tab changed is because the ROUTER is picking up the screen from MyStack (which is present in the selected tab) rather than picking the second Profile screen @YuvalSilver

Comment: You can test this theory by naming the "Profile" screen inside the "MyStack" to something else like "Profile1" and check if the tab is changed now. This will surely clear things out